# Get response is important to complete the HTTP POST process in Java?

Tags: java, post, http-post

One database supports the `culr` method to insert some data, such as `curl -d 'measurement,tag1=value1,tag2=value2 field1=123,field2=1.23' -X POST 'http://localhost:8428/write'`

And now, I want to convert the `curl` to java applications for me to conduct clearer data insertion.

So, I write the simple code down.

```java
String result = "";
try {
    String url = "http://localhost:8428/write";
    URL realUrl = new URL(url);
    URLConnection conn = realUrl.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestProperty("accept", "*/*");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);

    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    String content = "test,tag1=value1,tag2=value2 field1=123,field2=1.23";
    dos.write(content.getBytes());
    dos.flush();

    // Define BufferedReader to get URL reponse
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        result += line;
    }
    System.out.println(result);//print results
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exception," + e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If I comment the line 17:

```
    //BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
```

Then, the content cannot successfully appear in the database. I am not very skilled with the java.net.* package. Can anyone provide me some assumptions or insights about this confusion?

Comment: you do not set the request to `POST` , in your Header data you should add `method="post"` there...

Comment: @MartinFrank Meaninglessness. I try to set `conn.setRequestMethod("POST");`, but this problem still be there.

Comment: did you set the proper content length in your header - i don't see that there either ...